# Place two flow charts side by side

Tags: formatting, tikz-pic

I've read some of the other posts regarding placing figs side by side and I don't think this is duplicate because flow charts are not figures. Essentially I said my goal in the title, I want to place two flow charts side by side in the document.  Example of flow chart...

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {create design matrix};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {fit a linear model};
    \node [cloud, left of=identify] (expert) {eBayes};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {make contrasts matrix};
    \node [block, below of=evaluate, node distance=3cm] (decide) {apply Bayesian smoothing to standard errors};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {output: moderated t-stat};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- (stop);
    \path [line,dashed] (expert) -- (identify);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Essentially I want this flow chart to the left of another one just like it.  Does anyone know a method for completing this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the second `tikzpicture` environment after the first without a blank line between them

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}

\begin{document}



\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {create design matrix};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {fit a linear model};
    \node [cloud, left of=identify] (expert) {eBayes};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {make contrasts matrix};
    \node [block, below of=evaluate, node distance=3cm] (decide) {apply Bayesian smoothing to standard errors};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {output: moderated t-stat};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- (stop);
    \path [line,dashed] (expert) -- (identify);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {create design matrix};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {fit a linear model};
    \node [cloud, left of=identify] (expert) {eBayes};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {make contrasts matrix};
    \node [block, below of=evaluate, node distance=3cm] (decide) {apply Bayesian smoothing to standard errors};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {output: moderated t-stat};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- (stop);
    \path [line,dashed] (expert) -- (identify);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```